# Search all versions of a file in the undo tree

Tags: undo-redo

Is there an easier way to find a particular change in Vim's undo tree than just looking at random old versions of the file one at a time (either using vanilla VIM commands, Gundo, or another plugin)?

Ideally, I'd like to enter a search pattern to be matched against all of the diffs shown in the preview pane by Gundo, and then have Gundo show me which versions have diffs that match that search.

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/416658/199803) asks something almost identical, but the asker has accepted an answer that simply recommends Gundo, which, wonderful though it is, doesn't appear to do what I'm asking for.

I have pitched this as a [new feature for Gundo](https://bitbucket.org/sjl/gundo.vim/issue/45/search-through-diffs), but received no response.

**EDIT:** There is an [open request](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree/issues/48) for this feature for undotree.

**NOTE:** This question has been "manually migrated" from [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/704519/199803).

Comment: Note: `plugin-gundo` would be a good tag for this question, but unfortunately that tag doesn't exist yet, and I have no rep.

Comment: There's also [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree). I don't know how exactly it's different from gundo, or if it supports the feature you want, but you could check it out.

Comment: Bump! If you check the Gundo issue, someone has posted a fork that provides a searching feature.

Comment: @joeytwiddle I saw that! Haven't checked it out yet, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a [gundo fork](https://github.com/simnalamburt/vim-mundo) called "mundo" with this feature.

While in the undo-tree window, `/` will search the history rather than the text displayed in the window itself.

(Note: this feature appears to have been adopted from a [different gundo fork](https://github.com/dsummersl/gundo.vim). I'm not sure where credit for the implementation belongs, and I have **not** tried both forks to see which one works better.)

Answer (score 6):

In *some* cases, this might be enough:

```
:changes
```

Unfortunately it doesn't show a complete summary of your editing history.  It appears to show only **the line of text which you landed on** after each change.

That is good enough to display all single-line inserts or edits, but only the last line of a multi-line insert, and no deleted text.

It can only be searched visually, not automatically, although you could grab [this command](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/c8264794527c6be685829f08f63fd8dfa2903528/.vim/plugin/joeycommands.vim#L112-131) and then do:

```
:PipeCmd changes | less
```

which would allow searching with `/`.  Or just pipe to `grep` instead of `less`.

An alternative way to search that list would be to install the [Unite plugin](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) and then do:

```
:Unite change
```

Comment: Hm. Since doing a search-and-replace can make the word(s) being replaced completely invisible to `changes`, that's not terribly useful. What I'd really like is to be able to do `:%s/foo/bar/g`, then do a search for `foo` that would (reconstruct and) show me the last version of the file in which `foo` was present.